Meaning of the notation $\underline{x}$ for denoting coset.
The following is taken from Algebra: Notes from the underground by:  Aluffi, Paolo
Background
Example 6.21 Consider the ring $R=\frac{\Bbb{C}[x,y]}{(y^2-x^3)}$.  One can check that $R$ is an integral domain, that $\underline{x}$ is irreducible, and that $\underline{y}\not\in (\underline{x})$, where I am underlining elements of $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ to denote the corresponding cosets in $R$.  In $R,\underline{y^2}=\underline{x^3}$:  indeed, $\underline{y^2}-\underline{x^3}$ is the coset of $y^2-x^3,$ and this is $0$ in the quotient.  This show that $\underline{x}$ is not prime:  indeed, $\underline{y}\cdot\underline{y}=\underline{y^2}\in (\underline{x})$ and yet $\underline{y}\not\in (\underline{x})$.  So $\underline{x}$ is an irreducible element which is not prime.
Questions
I am having trouble understanding the line/notational explanation:  where I am underlining elements of $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ to denote the corresponding cosets in $R$. By $\underline{x}$, does Aluffi mean $\underline{x}=x+(x)$, so $\underline{y^2}=\underline{x^3}$ would mean $\underline{y^2}=y^2+(y^2)=\underline{x^3}=x^3+(x^3)$?  But then does $\underline{y^2}\in (\underline{x})$ mean $y^2+(y^2)=x+(x)$?
Thank you in advance

$$\underline a =\{\,f\in\mathbb C[x,y]\mid f=a+(y^2-x^3)g\text{ for some }g\in\mathbb C[x,y]\,\}$$

if I treat $$ as a function, the arugments for $$ would still be $,$? I also treak $$ as a two variables function, similarly for $$?  Also, in the case of $a^2$, is it denoted as $a^2 ={,f\in\mathbb C[x,y]\mid f=a^2+(y^2-x^3)g\text{ for some }g\in\mathbb C[x,y],}$, where $f,g$ remains the same notation wise?
